# How to use Scapy to construct an 802.11 data frame of a specific Sequence number？

Tags: python, wifi

The experimental scenario is for the sender to send an 802.11 data frame with a specific Sequence Number to the receiver. I used Scapy to construct the following code. The data frame sent by the sender starts from a specific sequence number, but when the receiver captured the packet, I found that the sequence number of the data frame still started from 0.

Code：

```
seq = 0x5070 
data = b'nihao,world!' 
for i in range(100):
    packet = RadioTap() 
   / Dot11(type=2, subtype=0, addr1=receiver_mac, addr2=sender_mac, addr3=receiver_mac, SC= seq)  
   / Raw(load=data) 
time.sleep(1)  
sendp(packet, iface="wlan0")
seq =  (seq + 0x10) & 0xFFFF
```

I would like to ask you all, what needs to be done so that the recipient or sniffer can receive the data frame with a specific Sequence Number?